# Exception: MySQL error when trying to re-index catalog_product_flat

Tags: mysql, exception

Was updating my indexes and noticed that one had failed, upon further investigation it looks like `catalog_product_flat` throws the following exception:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `ie2837g324t34t43r87g`.`sql-4416_38f7` (errno: 121 **"Duplicate key on write or update"**)' in /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

Does someone have a statement I can run to resolve this error?
or
Should I drop the catalog_product_flat table and re-index to recreate it?

**EDIT:**
Just tried running the repair tool and it says

[image]

I know I'm not the only one to have this because Google leads to links back to the old magento forum or people post that they fixed the issue but didn't outline what they've done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the `catalog_product_flat` tables became corrupted. Doing repairs with mysqlcheck and phpmyadmin didn't work because they are not supported by InnoDB.

To work around this issue, first backup your database.

Then run the following statement on your database to change the engine from InnoDB to MyISAM.

```
ALTER TABLE catalog_product_flat ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Run a repair on these tables.

Run the indexer for `catalog_product_flat` and it should complete successfully.